# Java: How to use the toString() method of one class in an other one?

Tags: java, class, tostring, composition

I'm working on this project while learning Java, I created a `Card` class that has a *toString()* method but when I'm trying to convert a `Card` object to a String in the `Deck` class I'm getting an *error*.

> Here is the Card class:

```
private final Rank cardRank;
private final Suit cardSuit;

public Card(Rank cardRank, Suit cardSuit){
    this.cardRank = cardRank;
    this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
}

public String toString(){
    return "The " + cardRank + " of " + cardSuit;
}
```

> Here is the Deck class:

```
private Card[] card = new Card[52];

public Deck(){
    int i = 0;
    for(Suit suit: Suit.values()){
        for(Rank rank: Rank.values()){
            card[i++] = (new Card(rank, suit));
        }
    }
}

public String toString(int i){
    return card[i];
}
```

Comment: Try using `return card[i].toString();`

Comment: And the error is.......?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that those methods should go inside of each class...

Comment: Don't forget to `Override` `toString` in `Rank` and `Suit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast a `Card` object into `String` object.

You can get the `String` representation of the `Card` object through `toString()` method.

Try like below

```
public String toString(int i){
    return card[i].toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've done what you said and changed a little bit:

    public void printDeck(){
        for(Card a: card)
            System.out.println(a.toString());
    }

Answer (score 1):

Calling return card[i] returns an object of type card. You have to actually call the toString() method so that your return object is a String and not a Card. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the `toString()` of each of your class does not have the `@Override` annotation, then you have to explicitly call the `toString()`.

Example:

```
return card[i].toString();
return "The " + cardRank.toString() + " of " + cardSuit.toString;
```

If you add the `@Override` annotation like this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "The " + cardRank.toString() + " of " + cardSuit.toString();
}
```

Then the Deck class `toString(int i)` can look like:

```
public String toString(int i){
    return card[i];
}
```

If you add the `@Override` to the `Rank` and `Suit` class, then the `Card` class `toString()` can look like:

```
public String toString(){
    return "The " + cardRank + " of " + cardSuit;
}
```